# Contao CMS error with https - 404 error

Tags: ssl, https, contao

Morning

I have a domain, www.example.com, which is a Contao 3.1.3 CMS website on Linux Apache.

I have just purchased and installed SSL certificate for the domain.

When I go to https://www.example.com (or https://example.com) all works fine.

when I try one of the other pages on the domain, http://www.example.com/folder/page.html all is fine, but with **https**://www.example.com/folder/page.html 
, I get an error:

> The requested URL /folder/page.html was not found on this server.

This does not happen with pages in the admin area, which all appear fine via https

Console log shows:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>   What is the solution to make all pages appear ok under https

I tried this: https://community.contao.org/de/showthread.php?43595-SSL-und-Contao
but it didn't help

I also checked https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.htm to see if the error is with the ssl certificate, but no problems found there.

Jez D

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The issue was actually with the directives on the virtual server.

Comment: Please share your solutions in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Problem cannot be on the SSL. From your explanation I would suggest you play around with disabling folder urls and url rewrite in the settings. Then make sure the page exists. I am sure from here you will be able trace down the problem.

Make sure also in the root page, the 'domain' field is on https if its set.

You can restore your folder and url rewrite settings when all is well

Comment: Where will I find  the root page, the 'domain' field?